# How to Sort Shoebox frames by order?

Tags: spritesheet

I ve been playing with ShoeBox lately and when trying to make a frame sheet i see that they don't appear alphabetically (frame_1 , frame_2 , etc). But they appear by best fitting. In Texture-Packer you can sort it by name but i cant see that option in ShoeBox.

How can i do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible in ShoeBox.

Why don't you just use TexturePacker since it already does what you want?

Comment: @Alexandre "It's not possible" sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: @Anko You're absolutely right. The answer was edited after the flag was raised.

Comment: Is there another software that does this. (You currently cant trim with TP Essential)